# How to solve Java Swing JPanel Repaint Lag inside of a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a Swing Jpanel thread which is loading an image and displaying it. The problem is that is falls behind and begins to lag.

I've looked into invokeLater but i am not quite sure where to implement it as the delay is still there.

My GUI thread code looks like this

```
ThreadDisplay(MutableObject mutableObject) {
    this.mutableObject = mutableObject;
}

public class ThreadDisplay implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    createPanel();
}
private void createPanel() {

    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shearing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(imgD);
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
protected class imageDisplay extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage fileToBuffer = null;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {

        try {
            if (mutableObject.getfirstElement() != null) {
                fileToBuffer = ImageIO.read(new File(mutableObject.getfirstElement()));
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.paintComponent(g);

        mutableObject.removeFirstElement();

        // g2d.dispose();

                try {
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();

                    double shiftx = .1;
                    double shifty = .1;
                    tx.shear(shiftx, shifty);

                    g2d.setTransform(tx);
                    String previousImage = null;
                    g2d.drawImage(fileToBuffer, tx, getParent());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                repaint();

    }
```

Comment: Ahhh...don't do this, like, EVER.  Start with, you should avoid loading resources within `paintComponent` and try and make you paint run as fast as possible...Second, get rid of the `invokeLater` from within the `paintComponent`!  Use a Swing `Timer` instead...

Comment: Seems problem here `ImageIO.read(new File(mutableObject.getfirstElement()));` , don't load resources at paintCOmponent as mentioned by MadProgrammer. Instead of preload them in constructor of `imageDisplay` and then use.

Comment: I second what @MadProgrammer states -- a paint or paintComponent method needs to be as fast as possible, and anything that slows it down slows down the perceived responsiveness of your program. Thus it should involve itself with painting and painting only, and should never read in images or other files or resources. Also, you should never call `repaint()` from within a painting method.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the invokelater should not have been there. I will make these adjustments and see if there is an improvement.

Comment: I have removed repaint from paintcomponent but, i am not sure where to place it.

Comment: @alex2410 i have moved the read into the constructor of imageDisplay but now all i can seem to retrieve is null values as it isn't updating accordingly.